# Word meaning "before sleeping"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means *before sleeping* or *before bed*, like how *postprandial* means *after dinner*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just as *post* + *prandial* [of or relating to a meal (as dinner)] means "after dinner," so *pre* + *somnial* [of or relating to sleep or dreams] can mean "before sleep" or "before bedtime."

So: *pre-somnial*.

> "But I was not yet able to trace my day-dreams back in the morning, as
>   I did those of the pre-somnial state." [J. Varendonck, *The psychology
>   of day-dreams*]

Comment: NB: The presomnial period tends, in the male of the species, to overlap with the postcoital, lasting an average of 45 seconds.

Comment: @onomatomaniak Is that a true fact (and from where)? Or did you make it up?

Comment: Maybe from the Aussie "male of the species", who I'm told is equally quick on the precoital side - *"Brace yerself, Sheila!"* being what passes for foreplay down under.

Comment: @z7sgѪ It is a false fact, but I stand by it nonetheless.

Comment: It's a false fact gained by personal hearsay :-b

Comment: Strange: "presomnolent" sounds syntactically much more sensible to me. Oh well.

Comment: @Billy: MW says _somnolent_ is "tending to induce drowsiness or sleepiness" vs "of or relating to sleep or dreams" for _somnial_, so not quite a fit. It does seem logical at first thought, though.

Answer (score 8):

***Bedtime***, or is that too childish?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very obscure Latin term used by medical professionals on prescriptions:

> - [Hora Somni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(H)) (H.S)
>
> > **At the hour of sleep; Medical shorthand for "at bedtime".** <sub>(Source: Wikipedia..)</sub>

[A preliminary Google search shows up a few results.](http://gog.is/hora+somni)

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for "hypnagogic"

Comment: That's not what the word means, by dictionaries